# for loop printing last number in sequence

Tags: c#

How can you print out the last number in the sequence and the amount of times it has ran in a for loop?

```
  int numOne = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < numOne; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

Comment: Some list called `TheList`, you use `TheList[TheList.Length-1]` to get the last item.

Comment: Why can't you just take the last number directly, without a loop? That would be much more efficient. It would really help me to give you the answer you need, if you describe how your input data looks like, and how do you get it.

Comment: Please be very specific

Comment: `int numOne = 50; for (int i = 0; i < numOne; i++) { Console.WriteLine(i); }` How can you print out the last number in the for loop similar to the list method. As an alternative can you add a for loop to the list? @Serega @ Zuoanqh @Rand Random @AustinWBryan

Comment: Sorry, Carlos - but your question is very hard to understand. I have no idea what you want. Maybe you can edit your question, with an example of your desired output.

Comment: So the for loop will print out a given set of numbers e.g.
`Int numOne = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < numOne; i++)
{ Console.WriteLine(i); }` i will therefor = to
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
But if I want the console to only display the last number (in this case 9) and no the entire inventory. 

@RandRandom

Comment: Then drop the for loop and just write an if statement `if (i == numOne -1) Console.WriteLine(i);`

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 5, 1 };
var lastItem = list.Last();
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lastItem, list.Count(item => item == lastItem));
```

Comment: @AustinWBryan - you kind of editing to much, make a new answer

Comment: @Serega How Can you populat the content of the list automatically. For example, a FOR LOOP will print out a list of items until the condition is met. Can use the for loop content to populate the list.